# ReactJs function trough parents then child with FunctionalComponent

Tags: reactjs

Im making a one page with reactJs. Maybe im not using the simply way to do that ... I don't know :/

[image: React app structure]
So I want to call the function from my menu to scroll into the element. But I have a parent, then a child.

Do you have any idea to that ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried assigning an html `id` to the element you want to scroll to, and then `href=#{the id}` on the button (it would need to be an `a` link element)

Comment: Works but not smooth :/

Comment: try setting the css of the page or scrollable element to `{ scroll-behavior: smooth }`

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a direct answer yo your question but you can pass functions as props to child components.

Small example would be like

```
class App extends Component {
  scrollFunc = () => {
    // Add scroll functionality
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ChildComp handleScroll={this.scrollFunc} />
    );
  }
}

class ChildComp extends Component {
  // Use is as this.props.handleScroll() inside this Component
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: My problem is child to components :/